# How to install an apk stored in private storage of android application?

Tags: android, permissions, installation, storage, internal

From my android app, I'm downloading an apk from the web, storing it in application's private storage `(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE))`

and trying to call the android package installer for this downloaded apk by,
`intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

startActivity(intent);`

but I'm getting an error which says
`Unable to open zip: /data/data/com.test/files/abc.apk : Permission denied`
in the LogCat

and,
`Parse Error: There is a problem parsing the package`
on the phone screen.

Is it happening because the apk file is in application's private storage so the Android package installer can't access it? If yes, is it somehow possible to still get the apk installed (with user's permission of course.) or Am I doing something wrong?

PS: Please don't assume the phone to be rooted.

Comment: Have you got "Settings|Application settings|Unknown sources" checked? unless this is checked the device will block you from installing APKs from anywhere except the Android Market.

Comment: By private storage, do you mean on the phone's internal storage or its sdcard? Either way are you sure the opening app has the correct app permissions to access the location? I know there is a specific setting for SDCARD access, but I am not sure about internal storage.

Comment: @Mark: yes I've done that, moreover I've given these permissions to the app as well WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, INTERNET, INSTALL_PACKAGES (though not all of these 3 might be actually needed)

Comment: @cjstehno: that is Internal Storage (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: well I know the file has been successfully saved in the internal storage, I've even checked the file size from the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Mark Allisons comment, my GUESS is that since you have the file saved to private storage with mode_private, only your application has read/write permission.  But you are trying to have the package installer read it which means that the file must be accessed by an External application and therefore should  either be MODE_WORLD_READABLE or MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE.

Or you could save it to external storage where it is world readable by default.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for now I've figured out a workaround (and which helped me confirming the exact problem also- *the problem was that installer couldn't access the apk file*). Now, I'm using MODE_WORLD_READABLE instead of MODE_PRIVATE while saving the file in internal storage, and the android installer is able to access the apk and can install it without any error. 
Actually, for me the main purpose of using internal storage was that users shouldn't be able to copy the apk file directly (assuming a simple threat model in which a user doesn't have rooted phone, but can browse through the SD card to find the apk and copy it). Though I'm still not sure whether the file is visible to a user now or not? I mean I'm (almost) fine if the downloaded apk can be accessed from an app in the phone, but can't be copied directly by the user.

Would be helpful if someone knowing the exact scope of MODE_WORLD_READABLE could elaborate on the same, specifically whether a file saved in this mode can be browsed in the (unrooted) phone. Also, is it possible to have a better strategy to safeguard the apk while still allowing the installer to access it?

Comment: They must have removed this functionality for I have tried it and still get the permission denied error. I can even see that the file was the appropriate read access, bummer :( Also that flag is deprecated API > 17

Answer (score -1):

MODE_WORLD_READABLE does say that it can be accessed by whole "world on the phone" so other apps can get it including file explorers. Some programs like es-file manager let you see contents on device private storage even if you are not rooted but don't let you change those files. Why don't you just delete apk file immediately after installation ? Also since you are downloading apk file in your application I am guessing you don't want to use play store but if that is not an issue see Licensing options for your app on: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html since there is probably use case that covers your requirements.